# Nokia Lumia 710 Upgrade from 7.5 to 7.8 on a Mac Computer

Tags: lumia, update, 7.8

Is there a way to upgrade a Nokia 710 from **Windows 7.5** to **7.8** using a **Mac** desktop computer with OSX version **10.10.1**?

The  **Windows 7 Phone Connector for Mac** app doesn't seem to be able to connect to the phone... it says it's connecting, but nothing happens.

Comment: At what stage are you getting this issue?

Comment: What version of the app are you using? and did you try **File > Allow Access to Folder** first?